# Decide if an employee is new or leavingemployee

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have employees with contracts in the database. I want to know if an employee is a new employee at a location. I have the following datastructure:

```
EmployeeId   Index    BeginDate    Enddate      HoursToWork   LocationId
12133         1       2013-01-01   2014-01-01    10            1
12133         2       2013-06-01   2014-01-01    20            1
12133         3       2012-01-01   2014-01-01    5             1
```

As you can see, an employee can have more than 1 contract on a location. Then Endate can be null.

Per location and per Month or Quarter I want to see how many employees are started. I want to use @Startdate and @Enddate parameters for the period I want have the data.

There are to many cases I should take into account. Like, the Index field is not Always increased together with the Begindate, like you can see at Index = 3.

Example:

I want to know how many employees are started in january 2013.

In this case nothing because the first contract was started on 2012-01-01. There are two new contracts but this employee is not new for the location. But if index 3 was not existing then whis should be a new employee.

It can be that a employee have two contract that starts on the same date and if he doesnt have before a contract then it is 1 new employee.

I already tried the following, which works when an employee just has 1 contract. But if there are more than 1 contracts then it is hard to decide if the employee is new:

```
declare @Startdate datetime set @Startdate = '2013-01-01'
declare @Enddate datetime set @Enddate = '2013-12-31'

select EmployeeId, Index, BeginDate, Enddate, HoursToWork, LocationId
 ,(case
      when BeginDate between @Startdate and @Enddate then 1
 end) as NewEmployee
 ,(case
      when Enddate between @Startdate and @Enddate then 1
 end) as LeavingEmployee

 from Contracts
```

Given the 3 records, this employee is not an new employee. I would like to have a output like:

```
LocationId  NewEmployee
   1            0
```

When I just have the first 2 records and I want know new employees in Janury 2013 then I expect:

```
LocationId  NewEmployee
   1            1
```

Comment: So anyhow you'll have to use a `Min` on `BeginDate` (or something equivalent). Now for LeavingEmployee, you don't mind if they have another contract after the first one ? Could you show which info you would like to retrieve with your 3 rows ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus See the edit, the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this for starting employee?

```
SELECT EmployeeID, LocationID, Min(StartDate) 
  FROM Contracts
GROUP BY EmployeeID, LocationID
HAVING Min(StartDate) between @Startdate and @Enddate
```

I would suggest something similar for Leavingemployee, but I would not spend much effort trying to get those into one query. It seems they are functionally different.

edit: es, it should be Min, not max. As for what is needed, i read "I want to see how many employees are started", and i didn't  see much reason to complicate matters.
If additional data is needed, it's always possible to move this to a subquery and select * where ... in subquery, but if it's not needed...

In order to only deal with active contract (contracts that are active during the time interval for the query) we can set the following rules:
A contract is active somewhere during the period we are looking at if its startdate < the parameter enddate *and* its enddate > the parameter startdate.

Adding that to our query, we get

```
SELECT EmployeeID, LocationID, Min(StartDate) 
  FROM Contracts
 WHERE Startdate <= @Enddate
   AND Enddate >= @Startdate
GROUP BY EmployeeID, LocationID
HAVING Min(StartDate) between @Startdate and @Enddate
```

Comment: 1. He seems to need Enddate and HoursToWork. You seem to forget this to make things easier 2. It should be Min, not Max, no ?

Comment: @oerkelens: This is not going to work if the employee was started on 2012-01-01. Because in that case he is not an new employee.

Comment: @Amedo: that is why it was changed to MIN. Since 2012-01-01 won't fall in your range, he is not selected as new employee.

Comment: @oerkelens: You are right. It looks like fine. How can I be sure that there are not another situation whereby it goes wrong? I testes the following situations: 3 contracts: 2 contract starts at the same time. and other is before the period selection.  2 contracts: they both starts between the period selection.

Comment: Enumerated all possible scnarios and test, that is the only way to be sure :)

Comment: Can I do the same for leaveEmployee, but Use Max?

Comment: If you want to know if (as far as you know at this point in time) it is the last time that the employee leaves, yes, you can do that (of course use enddate, not startdate :) )

Comment: @oerkelens: When there is a contract that is not active (2008-01-01 and ends 2009-01-01) but it is in the list with contracts then you will get wrong result. This means that you have to filter the active contracts first. Can you put this to in your answer please?

Comment: @Amedo: I added a where clause for that.